# Why is PHP session_destroy() not working?

Tags: php, session

I tried to destroy all session variable by using the `session_destroy()` method, but after using this method, the values are not destroyed.

Why is `session_destroy()` not working?

Is there any other way to destroy the session in PHP?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) 
{   
    session_destroy();   
    session_unset();     
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you are using.

Comment: "It won't work" is not much of a question. Can you explain what doesn't work? Can you `array_dump` `$_SESSION` for instance?

Comment: I'm still dieing to know what you meant by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471182/how-to-configure-gmail-in-php-at-run-time

Comment: in this case, just `unset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']);` after `session_destroy();` will clear the variable.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

After using `session_destroy()`, the session is destroyed behind the scenes. For some reason this doesn't affect the values in `$_SESSION`, which was already populated for this request, but it will be empty in future requests.

You can manually clear `$_SESSION` if you so desire (`$_SESSION = [];`).

Comment: as a note,  there is a function named `session_unset` if the OP needs that too.

Comment: @Gabi, `session_unset` is used for the PHP3-era global registration thing and should no longer be used.

Comment: session_destroy() does not remove the session cookie. It should be invalidated manually.

Comment: Thank you for `$_SESSION = [];` I am sure I should not use it but it clears out the session and that is all I need. To hack is to live.

Answer (score 127):

Make sure your session is initialized before destroying it.

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

i.e. you cannot destroy a session in logout.php if you initialized your session in index.php. You must start the session in logout.php before destroying it.

Comment: This answer is not correct. First, it's bad practice to suppress errors. Second, it destroys the session but it does not unset the session variables or invalidate the session cookie. This answer is very much incomplete.

Comment: @Nilpo the question here is "why is session_destroy not working", not "unset session variables". OP misunderstood what session_destroy really did.

Comment: @keanu_reeves: OP says (barring typos etc.) "I tried to destroy all session variables by using `session_destroy()`, but after using this method, the values are not destroyed." And OP seems to have accepted the correct answer accordingly. (However, there's still the mystery of how come that `session_unset()` didn't do it for him.)

Comment: @keanu_reeves, Ahh, but "studying" the edit history of the question, there's a complete alternative storyline lurking in there! :) It's quite possible that also the first editor (kevinji) (understandably) misunderstood the q., and then OP, misunderstanding the intent of the update, approved the changes, and it then all just seem to have gone hopelessly astray. :) (Nevertheless, the result is an informative page.)

Comment: Helped in my case..I created a logout.php and gave session destroy. Forgot starting  session first. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you need to clear the values of `$_SESSION`, set the array equal to an empty array:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Of course, you can't access the values of `$_SESSION` on another page once you call `session_destroy`, so it doesn't matter that much.

Try the following:

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array(); // Clears the $_SESSION variable
```

Comment: No, you don't need to call `session_unset`.   It's for the PHP3-era global registration thing that nobody should be using.

Comment: @Charles I thought so as well, but I didn't wish to modify the OP's code. That said, removed.

Comment: Great answer - navigating back no longer displays variables too.

Comment: I found this approach: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/10/3/5/ending-a-session Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

I had to also remove session cookies like this:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION = []; 

// If it's desired to kill the session, also 
// delete the session cookie. 
// Note: This will destroy the session, and 
// not just the session data! 
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) { 
    $params = session_get_cookie_params(); 
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, 
        $params["path"], $params["domain"], 
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"] 
    ); 
} 

// Finally, destroy the session. 
session_destroy();
```

Source: [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/session_unset-vs-session_destroy-in-php/)

Comment: Nice, clean & complete. Since 7.3 you could also do `setcookie(session_name(), '', session_get_cookie_params())`, if backdating the expiration isn't critical for some reason (the empty session ID should be enough, and most apps would set a new cookie soon enough anyway). Of course, if PHP provided some `unsetcookie($name[, $params])`, that would be even cleaner. (BTW, `[]` is preferred instead of `array()` nowadays. ;) )

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it works, but you also need to do `$_SESSION = array();` after the session_destroy to get rid of $_SESSION variables. However, avoid doing `unset($_SESSION)` because that makes sessions useless.

Comment: Having session destroyed (with session_destroy()) will make session useless aswell.

Comment: @IvoPereira The PHP manual states that both are necessary. session_destroy() alone will not do.

Comment: session_destroy() makes a particular session useless. unset($_SESSION) makes future sessions useless as well. From the PHP manual, `Caution
Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.`

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seems a new problem for me, using a new php server.  In the past never had an issue with sessions not ending.

In a test of sessions, I setup a session, ran a session count++ and closed the session.  Reloaded the page and to my surprise the variable remained.

I tried the following suggestion posted by mc10

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array(); // Clears the $_SESSION variable
```

However, that did not work.  I did not think it could work as the session was not active after destroying it, so I reversed it.

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

That worked, reloading the page starting sessios and reviewing the set variables all showed them empty/not-set.

Really not sure why session_destroy() does not work on this PHP Version 5.3.14 server.

Don't really care as long as I know how to clear the sessions.

Answer (score 1):

`session_destroy()` is effective after the page load is complete. So in the second upload, the session is terminated. But with `unset()` you can also log out from within the page.

Answer (score 0):

**if you destroy the session on `127.0.0.1` it will not affect on `localhost` and vice versa**

Answer (score -1):

It works , but sometimes it ***doesn't*** (check the below example)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name']="shankar";
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['name']; // Outputs shankar
}
session_destroy();
echo $_SESSION['name']; // Still outputs shankar
```

**Weird!! Right ?**

### How to overcome this ?

In the above scenario , if you replace **`session_destroy();`** with **`unset($_SESSION['name']);`** it works as expected.

**But i want to destroy all variables not just a single one !**

Yeah there is a fix for this too. Just unset the **`$_SESSION`** array. [*Credits Ivo Pereira*]

```
unset($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Instead of doing the foreach to destroy every key in $_SESSION, you could just delete them all using unset($_SESSION);

Comment: @shankar , When your page has loaded the "$_SESSION['name']" has defined as "shankar" that you defined. And next step you tried to destroy your session. So The "session_destroy();" function has removed all session from server.But the Point is "$_SESSION['name']" has already defined by "shankar". Of course, you session has destroyed. It will affect on only next page loading..Got it..?

Comment: Yeah i know that [See the first answer to this question]. I am referring to the current page.

Comment: Shankar, look at my last comment in my answer above yours. It's the PHP manual that says you should not unset $_SESSION. Instead, you set $_SESSION = array(), and that will unset the `$_SESSION['name']` in your example. This is the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Answer (score -3):

Add session_start(); before !Doctype Declaration

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <body>
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) 
{   
    session_destroy();   
    session_unset();     
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```