# php session unset do not work sometimes

Tags: php, session

I have this code to change session name:

```
 session_name(md5('seg'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
```

and this to logout:

```
session_name(md5('seg'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
session_start();

$user = $_SESSION["user"];

unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['user']);

session_destroy();
```

the problem is that sometimes it works, in first time. sometimes I need to click to logout about 3 times.
What may cause this?

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try to set whole session to empty array:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

// $_SESSION is still accessible till page change.
```