# session can not be cleared

Tags: php, session

Look at the example code directly:

```
<?php
// page1.php

session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #1';

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();
echo '<br /><a href="page2.php">page 2</a>';

?>
```

And another page:

```
<?php
// page2.php

session_destroy();
session_unset();
session_start();

echo 'Welcome to page #2<br />';

echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
echo $_SESSION['animal'];   // cat
echo date('Y m d H:i:s', $_SESSION['time']);

echo '<br /><a href="page1.php">page 1</a>';
?>
```

Although I call `session_destroy(), session_unset(),` I still get the data coming from `page1.` why? and how to really clear the session? Thanks!

Comment: put `session_start();` on top of second page and try

Comment: possible duplicate of [why session\_destroy() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
```

But just for clarity, this is happening to you because you have to call session_start() first

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_unset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the session first on the second page **page2.php**.Put **session_start();** at the top on second page.