# Destroy session upon refresh

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to destroy the session information upon refresh. The problem here is that everytime I refresh, the data still appears on the table. How do i set the table data to null upon refresh?

```
<?php
        $value = $_SESSION["data"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM datas WHERE CONCAT(`code`,`name`, `ID`, `cost`) LIKE '%".$value."%'";
        $search = filterTable($query);
    if (isset($_SESSION["data"])) {
       if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != $_SESSION["data"]) {
            session_destroy();
       }
    }
    function filterTable($query)
    {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databasename");
        $filter = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $filter;
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can use Javascript here. You can clear your table in 'Document.ready' function. Thus, for each refresh the table will become blank.

Comment: maybe the problem is this condition: if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != $_SESSION["data"]). Try to double check this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear all session variables after you have retrieved them once, you can use PHPs [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) function.

In your code it would be:

```
$value = $_SESSION["data"];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM datas WHERE CONCAT(`code`,`name`, `ID`, `cost`) LIKE '%".$value."%'";
    $search = filterTable($query);
if (isset($_SESSION["data"])) {
   if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != $_SESSION["data"]) {
        session_unset();
   }
}
```

This should clear all session data so when the page is refreshed, `$value` should be null.

You can also try to use [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove the values. E.g.

```
unset($_SESSION['data']);
```

Comment: hi, unfortunately the session wasn't destroyed :(

Answer (score 0):

one alternative way is to set session as empty array, and that would help you:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

**EDIT**

did you try first to destroy and then to set empty array like:

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
```

maybe this post might help you: [why session_destroy() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working)

Comment: this does't work either, or am I placing it in a wrong order?

Answer (score -1):

We cannot unset session variable through javascript or ajax. So we have to pass the control first to php using javascript and ajax. From there you can unset session data :

```
//put this line of code in that page you are planning to refresh.
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                if (xmlHttp==null){
                    alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                    return;
                }
                var base_url="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"
                var url=base_url + 'controller/function_name';
               // url +=id;
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
                xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlHttp.send(null);

  };

//your function in php will be 

public function function_name(){

        $newdata =  array(

                            'session_variable' =>0       
                    );

        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
    }
```