# Unable to unset session on clicking link

Tags: php, session-variables

I have set `session_start()` on every page. Now, I want to *unset session*

```
 <div style="text-align: center;">
     <a href="clearorder.php">Clear order</a>
      </div>
```

Here is my **`clearorder.php`**

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION["cart"] = array();
session_destroy(); 
header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

But the session is not clearing and displaying the data of the session. What could I be missing?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: First of all there might be something wrong with your logic, as you are assigning an empty `array()` to your session `cart` variable, it will always be empty. Try to assign it something, and then see if the value appears after you `session_destroy();` Also refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working

Comment: What session data is it still displaying ?

Comment: Is that the whole code of clearorder.php?

Answer (score 0):

First Destroy Session and then set an empty array so it will be clear,

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array(); // Clears the $_SESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code after clicking the below code on that page your rdirecting after click on logout button:

```
Session_start(); 
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.i hope it will help you

```
session_destroy();
        redirect(base_url('login'), 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i got my log out button to work was simply

```
"Button that leads to (Example: logout.php)"
<?php
Session_start();
Session_destroy();
Header("Location: "Whatever page you want" ");
?>
```